# The existence of the roots of an holomorphic function on an open connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

Let $U$ be an open connected domain and $D$ be an open disk such that  the closure of $D$ is a subset of $U$. Suppose $f\in H(U)$, i.e., $f$ is holomorphic in $U$, and that $f$ is not constant. Show that if $|f|$ is constant on the boundry of $D$, then $f$ has at least one zero in $D$.

**My answer:**

$|f| = c$ on $\partial D \implies$ there exists $M>0$ such that  $|f(z)|=M$ for all $z\in\partial D$, and since $f\in H(U)$ then $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z\in D$. Suppose that $f$ has no roots in $D$. Then $1∕f\in H(D)$. If $z\in\partial D$  then  $|1 ∕ f(z)|=1∕ M$ then  $|1 ∕ f(z)|\leq 1∕ M$ for all  $z\in D$ but  $|f(z)|\leq M$  for all $z\in D$ then  $|1 ∕ f(z)|\geq 1∕ M$ for all $z\in D$ so we get  $|1 ∕ f(z)|=1∕ M$ for all $z\in D$ then $|f(z)|=M$  for all $z\in D$ and since $D$ is open and connected then $f$ is constant on $D$, contradiction.
Is that right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|f| = c$ on $\partial D \implies$ there exists $M>0$ such that  $|f(z)|=M$ for all $z\in\partial D$, and since $f\in H(U)$ then $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z\in D$. Suppose that $f$ has no roots in $D$. Then $1∕f\in H(D)$. If $z\in\partial D$  then  $|1 ∕ f(z)|=1∕ M$ then  $|1 ∕ f(z)|\leq 1∕ M$ for all  $z\in D$ but  $|f(z)|\leq M$  for all $z\in D$ then  $|1 ∕ f(z)|\geq 1∕ M$ for all $z\in D$ so we get  $|1 ∕ f(z)|=1∕ M$ for all $z\in D$ then $|f(z)|=M$  for all $z\in D$ and since $D$ is open and connected then $f$ is constant on $D$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. Though, you should probably mention that you used the maximum modulus principle at least once and why you are allowed to (if $D$ was not bounded, the conclusion would not have been true).

Comment: In general, in which cases I am allowed to use the maximum modulus principle?

Comment: @MalakDiab the maximum modulus principle is more general and this is one consequence of it that uses the compactness of $\overline D$. The MMP states that if $f$ is analytic on a domain $D$ and there exists $z_0 \in D$ such that $|f(z_0)| \ge |f(z)|$ for all $z \in D$, then $f$ is constant. Now suppose that $D$ is bounded. Then, $\overline D$ is compact and so $|f|$, being continuous, attains a maximum on $\overline D$ say at $z_0$. If $z_0 \in \partial D$, we are done. If not, then by MMP $f$ is constant on $D$, and we are done.

Comment: @MalakDiab having now written in details what I had in mind, I think that your argument is not quite precise (at the step where you conclude that $|f(z)| \le M$ for all $z \in D$). If it is not clear to you how to construct a correct proof from here, let me know and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: ok, thanks in advance

Comment: In my previous exercise, I have proved that if an holomorphic function f has a local maximum M on the boundary of a bounded set D then |f(z)|<= M   For all z in D.

Comment: so I used what I have already proved to write what is written in this answer

Comment: @MalakDiab if that's the case, then there is no need to use the MMP and your argument suffices. Anyway, assuming that you had not proved that, what you need to do is just elaborate more at the step $|f(z)| \le M$. Namely, you need to argue as I did in the comment: if $z_0 \notin \partial D$, then by MMP $f$ is constant on $D$. Otherwise, you may say that $|f(z)| \le M$ for all $z \in D$ and continue from there.